# correct syntax for .css element to be added to droppable for html tags

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have not worked long with jquery. I am trying to create a droppable element inside another droppable element.

That is working fine by nesting it, but since the new item doesn't have a class prior to creation, I want to format the CSS attributes during creation.

I am using the `.css{()}` function, which works fine for all normal formatting. 
Yet, I cannot figure out the syntax to set, for instance, H1 or H2 to none or alter tags within the new droppable clone.

I tried adding the `h2 {display: 'none'}`, as a line, but it isn't accepting that format.

```
    //It is the bottom line of code, but this is to show how it is nested
    //which is why I am trying to set the css this way.
        drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this)
            .append(ui.helper.clone(false)
            .css({
            position: 'relative',
            left: '0px',
            top: '0px',
            height: "75px",
            width: "100%"
        })
            .droppable({
                accept: "#gallery > li",
                classes: {
                 "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
                 },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .append(ui.helper.clone(false)
                .css({
                position: 'relative',
                display: 'inline-block',
                padding: '1%',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                height: "36px",
                width: "auto",
                h2 {display: 'none'} //right here is the problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there is a syntax problem in your code in the last line :

```
$(this)
                .append(ui.helper.clone(false)
                .css({
                position: 'relative',
                display: 'inline-block',
                padding: '1%',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                height: "36px",
                width: "auto"});//Here you should close your style
                //Maybe here you mean to find the H2 element who is a child of this element then
                .find('h2').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my friend also texted me a similar syntax. It is hard jumping into JqueryUI without having worked much with any of it before. I used to avoid it and just write all the stuff from scratch, but it is nice to have a simplified way to add functionality that doesn't take days to write.

Comment: @josephx no problem a little more of project and you'll accustom with it :)